# Docker not root user needs psswd.fake?

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am trying to run my docker image locally with non root privileges, looking in my jenkins file I see that when docker is invoked it is used the following. Where this `passwd.fake` is mounted in the docker

```
docker {
          image 'a:b'
          reuseNode true
          args '-v $WORKSPACE/passwd.fake:/etc/passwd'
}
```

Tracing the `args` command I found this one

```
steps{
      sh 'echo xxx:x:$(id -u):$(id -g)::${WORKSPACE}:/bin/sh > passwd.fake'
      ...
      }
```

What does this passwd.fake contains and why is it needed? In case I want to run my docker locally what command should I use? Trying this

```
hostUid=$(id -u jj)
hostGid=$(id -g jj)
cat passwd.fake
echo "$hostUid:$hostGid::$WORKSPACE:/bin/sh">$WORKSPACE/passwd.fake
docker run -u $hostUid:$hostGid -v "$WORKSPACEpasswd.fake:/etc/passwd"
```

generates this error

```
error   29-Mar-2024 14:46:51    /bin/run.sh: 57: cannot create //.bashrc: Permission denied
error   29-Mar-2024 14:46:51    /bin/run.sh: 57: cannot create //.bashrc: Permission denied
error   29-Mar-2024 14:46:51    sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
error   29-Mar-2024 14:46:51    sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing.  There's no particular requirement for a user to exist in `/etc/passwd`; `docker run -u 12345 ...` will work even if that user isn't listed in the password file.  The error message mentions a `.bashrc` file, which won't normally be used in a container, and `sudo`, which isn't usually necessary in Docker at all.  Do you have more details of what the container is actually doing?